# Множественная загрузка файлов

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать множественную загрузку файлов (фотографий) на сервер? Поле для выбора файлов должно быть одно, а выбрать по кнопке выбора должно быть можно любое количество файйлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант: [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support), я сразу вам дал ссылку на поддержку браузеров, чтобы время не тратить, если вас устроит такой подход, то можете смело использовать этот плагин, вот что сказано по поводу IE:

```
Internet Explorer has no support for multiple file selection, but allows to add multiple files to the upload queue by selecting files multiple times.
```

перевести это все не сложно, в принципе написано что как таковой множественной загрузки файлов IE не поддерживает, но позволяет добавлять несколько файлов в очередь загрузки выбирая файлы по отдельности.

Comment: Спасибо, я нашла плагин plupload, он поддерживает множественную загрузку, но никак не могу его заставить работать, т.е. он пишет, что файлы загрузились, а в папку ничего не попадает на сервере.

Comment: я сначала тестировала  jQuery-File-Upload в IE9 и думала, что он не поддерживает выбор сразу нескольких файлов, теперь поняла, что в других браузерах - поддерживает.

Answer (score 3):

1. берере jQuery плагин ajax-upload например
2. вешаете bind на input=file и при выборе файла заливаете на сервер в tmp в ответ возвращаете какую-то инфу по файлу и из полученной инфы генерите input=checkbox паример
3. сабимитите форму с этими чекбоксами, а на сервере просто копируете/переносите из tmp в куда-вам-надо и делаете-что-вам-надо
4. параллельно должен работать хрон чтобы периодически чистить tmp от лишнего хлама который там копится

Comment: Спасибо, а там можно будет выбрать несколько файлов сразу для одного поля?

Comment: В самом html тэге надо указать multiple
<input type="file" multiple="true"/>

Comment: у такого решения нет поддержки IE и практически нет поддержки в сафари, отвратительная поддержка в опере и фф

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery MultiUpload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)